# Adding delivery date with datepicker to a loop of products

Tags: php, wordpress, datepicker

I'm trying to get a loop of products to have a delivery date field and use the datepicker for the field. I'm looking through the docs on how to increment an id or unique id of some sort for the datepicker to work and keep the delivery date associated with the product. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**PHP**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
    <!-- PROD GRID ============================================================ -->
      <!-- PROD. ITEM -->
        <div class="col-sm-6  container-cart">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- IMAGE CONTAINER-->
            <?php if ($product->image_url): ?>
              <img src="<?=$product->image_url ?>" />
            <?php endif // image_url ?>
            <!--END IMAGE CONTAINER-->
            <!-- CAPTION -->
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="well">
                <h3 class="product-title"><?= $product->title ?></h3>
                <p class="product-description"><?= $product->description ?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm scrow">
                  <p class="lead">
                    <span id="item-price">$<?= money_format('%i', $product->price) ?></span>
                    <input type="hidden" class="price-integer form-control" value="<?= money_format('%i', $product->price) ?>">
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm scrow">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Quantity</span>
                  <input type="text" name="surgecart_products[<?=$product->id ?>]" id="quantity" class="quantity form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$_POST['surgecart_products['. $product->id . ']'] ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm scrow">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Delivery Date</span>
                  <input type="text" name="surgecart_products[<?=$product->id ?>]" id="datepicker" class="delivery-date form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$_POST['surgecart_products['. $product->id . ']'] ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm scrow">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="text" name="base-total" id="base-total" class="readonly base-total form-control" value="" readonly>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--END CAPTION -->
          </div>
          <!-- END: THUMBNAIL -->
        </div>
      <?php endforeach // products ?>
      <!-- PROD. ITEM -->
    </div>
```

And of course the datepicker:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: If am able to understand your problem, you want to initialize multiple `datepicker` for each product. If yes you can use something like this `div[id^="product_"]` or use normal `javascript` function to initialize your date picker.

Comment: @Richie yes this is correct and I'm assuming that I use `div[id^="product_"]` in the jQuery selector correct? Thanks!